# Excel 2013 VBA user forms add countIf calculation

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to build a score card. On the form I have a few questions and comboboxes with `yes`, `no`, `N/A` and results.

What I am trying to do is create a result that works like this:

```
If ComboBox1=yes, ComboBox2=no, ComboBox3=yes and ComboBox4=N/A
```

then the calculation will be as such:

```
evaluate.Lable1 = ((countif(Range(ComboBox1,ComboBox2,ComboBox3,ComboBox4),="yes")/(Counta(Range(ComboBox1,ComboBox2,ComboBox3,ComboBox4))-((countif(Range(ComboBox1,ComboBox2,ComboBox3,ComboBox4),="N/A")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit of research I found that the IIF code worked. so the answer to this is :

```
'Get the Numerator
a = IIf(ComboBox1.Value = "Yes", 1, 0) + IIf(ComboBox2.Value = "Yes", 1, 0)_     
+ IIf(ComboBox3.Value = "Yes", 1, 0) + IIf(ComboBox4.Value = "Yes", 1, 0)
'Get the Denominator
b = 4 - IIf(ComboBox1.Value = "N/A", 1, 0) - IIf(ComboBox2.Value = "N/A", 1, 0)
  - IIf(ComboBox3.Value = "N/A", 1, 0) - IIf(ComboBox4.Value = "N/A", 1, 0)
'Put the Numerator and Denominator together as a percentage
 Lable1.Text = Format(a / b, "00.00%")
```